# How can I use map-reduce in this situation?

Tags: oracle, hadoop

I thought I can get an output that I want to see with this mapper code and a result of an oracle query.

```
outputkey.set(column[0] +","+column[1]){
 if(column[1].contains("ora-"))
   context.write(outputkey,outputvalue)
}

select record_id, message_text
from x$dbgalertext;
```

But actually, these code couldn't do anything.

I want to get this result using Hadoop and Oracle query.

```
date         error      sum of errors
column1     column2   column 3
07-26      ora-00000    10
07-26      ora-00001    20
07-27      ora-00008    12
...          ...         ...
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve with just mapper, you also need to have reducer code. Where all the similar keys get aggregated to count for sum of errors.

With your present code you would get output as

```
07-27,ora-00008 1
...
...
```

At the reducer you would receive all keys with iterable of values. So just having a count of that would be your sum of errors.

```
context.write((key.split(,)[0]+" "+key.split(,)[1]),value.size());
```